# Is there a way to export Crystal reports formulas to a readable document?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a very complicated Crystal Reports XI rpt file with 30+ group header sections, 
each with its own suppress (No Drill-Down) formula.  I would like to document this report
in a separate ASCII txt file so I can get an overview of the report.  Is there any tool or any way I can export Crystal Reports XI formulas without going through each section and copying them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The export functionality provides an export format called "Report Definition" which will export the complete definition, including all formulas, to a text file.

Comment: 9 1/2 years later, and I'm trying to do the same thing. For others looking, this will export all formulas that are directly used in the report, but it doesn't seem to export formulas that are only used in other formulas. https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1211554

Answer (score 0):

[RptToXml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/) is an open-source project with that goal in mind.